# Multiple Comparisons for 2D list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have 2D lists of the form:

```
xyPositions = [[474, 318], [543, 432], [633, 328], [548, 514]]
```

Sometimes there are 4 (as here), 8, 10, 12 or 16 pairs of xy coordinates in these lists.

The following little function I've written will test whether two sets of x y coordinates overlap, e,g., `dotOverlap( [55, 99], [399, 88] )`

However, I'm somewhat embarrassed to say I cannot think of an easy way to test all possible cases of overlap (i.e., pairwise comparisons):

```
#    #
1 to 2
1 to 3
1 to 4
2 to 3
2 to 4
3 to 4
```

How might I programmatically go about doing this?

---

```
from math import sqrt
ClearanceRadius = 7     # pixels
def dotOverlap(p1, p2):

    x1 = p1[0]
    y1 = p1[1]
    x2 = p2[0]
    y2 = p2[1]

    overLapTest = None

    d = sqrt( (y2 - y1)**2 + (x2 - x1)**2 )

    if ClearanceRadius*2 < d:
        overLapTest = False
    elif ClearanceRadius*2 > d:
        overLapTest = True

    return(overLapTest)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to generate all the combinations and you can unpack the combinations over your function, one by one, like this

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> xyPositions = [[474, 318], [543, 432], [633, 328], [548, 514]]
>>> [dotOverlap(*items) for items in combinations(xyPositions, r=2)]
[False, False, False, False, False, False]
```